# Connect observations with lines to a common point (i.e. (0,0))

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect observations from my df with a common point, i.e. the centerpoint (0,0) using *ggplot2*.

```
x y
1 5 4
2 -4 -2
3 -1 5
4 2  -8
```

Using geom_point(), I get the following.
[image: Plot using geom_point()]

Now, I would like to have lines connecting the four observations with the centerpoint at (0,0), like in the following (not made with R):

[image: Illustration of what I would like to have]

Is this possible at all using *ggplot2*?

Comment: Yes, easy. Use `geom_segment`.

Comment: omg, thank you! why didn't I think of geom_segment? anyway, this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) + geom_segment(aes(xend=0, yend=0))
```

<sub>Answer based on [@roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) comments on a question.</sub>